# Communicating in c# with a process that sometimes freezes

Tags: c#, process, freeze

I'm trying to build a `C#` application that uses `MPC-HC's` `API` to control the video player. It sends windows messages back and forth and it is working.

Except that `MPC-HC` sometimes freezes, and when it does, my application freezes as well.

Is there a way I could
1. Prevent my application from freezing
2. Detect whether `MPC-HC` window is responsive
3. Kill process and re-open media player window if frozen

I have been able to write code for 2 and 3, as well as to detect responsiveness before sending a command, but if `MPC-HC` freezes when sending an API command, my application freezes and there's nothing I can do.

Is there any work-around? Perhaps having a 3rd process in the middle and my application would only communicate with that middle process in a way that can't freeze the main app (if that's possible)?

**Edit:** Turns out I previously tested multi-threading with the 'await' keyword, which doesn't actually start any new thread, and that's why the process still froze! If I do properly create a new thread, then it's fine... This code works and replaces the whole program I wrote below

```
Dim T As New Task(Function() Comm.SendMsg(CommWnd.SYSMSG.WM_COPYDATA, cmd, param))
T.Start()
If T.Wait(3000) = False Then
    MpcProcess.Kill()
End If
```

That's what happens when you lag behind in studying new features

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to multithreading (one responsive thread for your UI, one for the commands for example), but it's just an idea ;)

Comment: try run the player in separate thread then the main thread should not stop "freeze"

Answer (score 0):

I first tried with creating separate threads but that didn't work. The whole application still froze.

I did, however, find a solution: create a new process that monitors the video player. If it freezes, it freezes my main application, but the separate process is still running and can kill it.

Here's the code for this, in case anyone else comes across a similar issue.

File: Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProcessWatcher {
    public class Program {
        private static WatcherThread watcher;

        /// <summary>
        /// Application entry point
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Command-line parameters</param>
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // args = new string[] { "mpc-hc", "" };

            if (args.Length < 2) {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
@"Call with these parameters
ProcessWatcher [WatchProcess] [HostProcess] [Interval]
[WatchProcess]: Name of the process to monitor and kill if frozen.
[HostProcess]: When specified host process stops, end program.
[Interval]: (optional) Interval in milliseconds between checks. Default is 2000.

Example:
ProcessWatcher mpc-hc NaturalGroundingPlayer 2000");
                return;
            }

            string WatchProcess = args[0];
            string HostProcess = args[1];
            int Interval = args.Length > 2 ? Int32.Parse(args[2]) : 2000;

            watcher = new WatcherThread(WatchProcess, HostProcess, Interval);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

File: ProcessWatcher.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProcessWatcher {
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks regularly whether specified process is responsive. If not, kill it.
    /// </summary>
    public class WatcherThread {
        private string processWatch;
        private string processHost;
        private Timer timer;

        public WatcherThread(string processWatch, string processHost, int interval) {
            this.processWatch = processWatch;
            this.processHost = processHost;
            timer = new Timer(KillIfFrozen, null, interval, interval);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Kills the watched process if it is not responsive.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state">null</param>
        public void KillIfFrozen(Object state) {
            Process[] ProcessList = Process.GetProcessesByName(processWatch);
            foreach (Process item in ProcessList) {
                if (item.Responding == false) {
                    // Wait 1500ms for the process to respond
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        Thread.Sleep(250);
                        if (item.Responding)
                            break;
                    }

                    // If still not responsive, kill process.
                    if (item.Responding == false) {
                        try {
                            // This throws an "Access denied" exception but still stops the process.
                            item.Kill();
                        } catch {}
                    }
                }
            }

            // If host process is closed, end program.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(processHost)) {
                ProcessList = Process.GetProcessesByName(processHost);
                if (ProcessList.Length == 0) {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use Process.Start in the main application to run this application. When the main application stops, this detects it and stops as well.

Now, in order for the main application process to stop when ending execution in Visual Studio, under the main application project properties, you have to go under Debug and disable "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"